# Optional[] type in mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis, mypy

I have the following nested functions

```
from typing import Optional

def outer(
    outer_foo:int,
    outer_bar:Optional[int] = 5
):
    return inner(outer_foo, outer_bar)

def inner(
    inner_foo:int,
    inner_bar:int
):
    return inner_foo+inner_bar

print(outer((1)))
```

and `mypy` throws the following error:

```
error: Argument 2 to "inner" has incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "int"
```

given that I gave an `int` as default value of `outer_bar`, I don't see a potential issue. However, I was able to solve the mypy error changing the code to this:

```
from typing import Optional

def outer(
    outer_foo:int,
    outer_bar:Optional[int] = None
):
    if outer_bar is None:
        outer_bar = 5
    return inner(outer_foo, outer_bar)

def inner(
    inner_foo:int,
    inner_bar:int
):
    return inner_foo+inner_bar

print(outer((1)))
```

Which seems to be defeating the usefulness of default arguments in the declaration. Is this the best/pythonic way to do it?

Comment: `Optional` means it can be `None`. Not that it is a default argument.

Comment: *You* told it the type was `Optional`, which by definition means that it can be `None`. That means if you call `outer` with `outer(1, None)`, that will be valid, but then, there would be an error when that `None` passed to `inner`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is a default value, then  `outer_bar` isn't an `Optional` as it'll not be `None`

```py
def outer(outer_foo: int, outer_bar: int = 5):
    return inner(outer_foo, outer_bar)
```

---

Note, when the default value needs to be a empty list, regarding ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) use `None` as default value, then `or []`

```py
def outer(outer_foo: int, outer_bar: Optional[list[int]] = None):
    return inner(outer_foo, outer_bar or [])
```